# Angular2 Components :: ViewChild / ContentChild by class

Tags: angular

I am trying to design an expandable component like so:

```
<collapsable [expanded]="myFlag">
  <div title>Summary</div>
  <div alternate-title>Heading</div>
  <div content>Details</div>
</collapsable>
```

The `alternate-title` portion is supposed to be optional. When `myFlag = false`, the component should render only:

```
<div title>Summary</div>
```

However, when `myFlag = true`, the component should render one of the following:

```
// If alternate-title exists..
<div alternate-title>Heading</div>
<div content>Details</div>

// If alternate-title does not exist..
<div title>Summary</div>
<div content>Details</div>
```

Right now, I have the template for this component defined as follows:

```
<ng-content *ngIf="!expanded" select="[title]"></ng-content>
<ng-content *ngIf="expanded"  select="[alternate-title]"></ng-content>
<ng-content *ngIf="expanded"  select="[content]"></ng-content>
```

This works fine for the first scenario (if `alternate-title` exists). However, in the second scenario, it doesn't work (obviously). To get it to work for the second scenario, I need to get a reference to `alternate-title` in my component. One way to do that is below:

```
// In page.html..
<div #alternateTitle alternate-title>...</div>

// In component.ts
@ContentChild('alternateTitle') alternateTitle: ElementRef;
```

However, I don't like this approach as it forces me to define a local variable for `alternate-title` which is redundant.

Is there a way I can get a reference to `alternate-title` in my component to check whether or not the user of my component defined it or not?

Comment: You can query for it (direct DOM access) otherwise I don't see a way except the template variable.

Comment: I didn't think of that! =) Would you mind showing me how I might query for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need a wrapper element with a template variable:

```ts
<ng-content *ngIf="!expanded" select="[title]"></ng-content>
<span #titleWrapper><ng-content *ngIf="expanded"  select="[alternate-title]"></span></ng-content>
<ng-content *ngIf="expanded"  select="[content]"></ng-content>
```

Then we can query the element using `@ViewChild()` and then check if it contains the content we are interesed in:

```ts
@ViewChild('titleWrapper') titleWrapper:ElementRef;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  let title = this.titleWrapper.nativeElement.querySelector('[alternative-title]');
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But this approach also forces declaration of a local variable.. =(

Comment: But only once in your component, not every time you use use the component. Why do you think this is a disadvantage?

Comment: Apologies for being hasty.. You're right.. This works perfectly! Thanks mate.. =)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Disadvantage because we need to declare two identifier to a same tag? I think that `altenative-title` should be consider like `#alternative-title`.

Comment: @titusfx I didn't say it's a sleek or prefect solution ;-) I think it's the best Angular allows currently though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer well kind of. Because we can do the select manually. I mean, I didn't see it in source code. But I bet that `select is a directive` which search in the ng-content finding elements with those tags specified. `And 'cause angular don't allow dynamic template ref's ( I mean #adynamicName )` it can't be reuse as AweSIM needs. And they probably have that problem because one time run, but I think they could implement a type of priority runs and have a "one run time" . ( I mean like the expression 3+3*3 which is 12 ).They have that problem in several scenarios.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer In any case a directive can be made like `select` which inject another directive for `dynamic access` ( without being scare of a dirtyHtml ). But in this scenario your solutions is the simpler solution ( **the problem is that doesn't work for all scenarios**, mainly in scenarios where adding a div can breaks the html ) and from our perspective its expensive in resources implementing a new select directive solution which in some cases is mandatory.